# Length detection in JSON (nested structure) - Angular View

Tags: angularjs, json

**Example JSON Structure**

```
{
  "holding": [
    {
      "company": 1,
      "employee": [
        { "id": 1, "name": "John"},
        { "id": 2, "name": "Michael"},
        { "id": 3, "name": "George"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "company": 2,
      "employee": [
        { "id": 1, "name": "Madonna"},
        { "id": 2, "name": "Harry"}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The structure above is available in the view as

```
{{ holding }}
```

Holding has 5 employees, how can I detect this in Angular? Is there a simple method? I need this possibility in the View, something like

```
{{ holding.length }}  // 2
```

What I need is (PSEUDO CODE):

```
{{ length of all employees in holding }} // 5
```

**If possible:** I need a view-only-solution, that doesn't modify the controller..

Controller-solutions below (answers) do work properly.

Comment: i think you need to do a loop in order to achieve that, i am not sure there is another way, other than using third party libraries or looping it your self.

Comment: A manager need a view with some numbers and I've no access to the controller, I know only its existing structure. So it is in big companies, you have to work miracles :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array's [Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function. It takes a function that's called for each element of an array, taking the result of the last iteration (I called it `count`, but it doesn't have to be a numeric result) and the current element (`company`, since each element of holding represents a company). The parameter after the function is optional, and is used to specify an initial value for `count`, or whatever type of element you're working with.

```
var totalEmployees = parentObject.holding.reduce(function(count, company){
        return +count + +company.employee.length;
    }, 0);
```

You didn't provide a name to the object containing `holding`, so I just called it `parentObject`.

Another benefit is that this is vanilla JS, and so can be used even when Angular isn't available.

Comment: Thank you @Harris: Does it work within {{ .. }} in an Angular view ?

Comment: I haven't tried it like that, but I think it hypothetically should, since it's externally a single function call with a single end-result/return value (even though internally it calls the provided function a varied number of times). However, I would put it in a function in the controller and call _that_, as it makes your logic less exposed in the view, and keeps it all in once place.

Comment: And thanks @itamar. It just happened to be something I've been using a lot lately.

Comment: sorry, it does not work in this constallation in the view, but it is an elegant answer for VanilaJS..

Comment: What does it display when you try it in the view?

Comment: StackOverflow wants any further comments to be in chat- http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98146/discussion-between-harris-weinstein-and-vienna

Answer (score 0):

Using `angular.forEach` here is a simple option to produce count.

```
 angular.module('app', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.cnt=0;
  $scope.hiArray = [];
  $scope.myarr={
  "holding": [
    {
      "company": 1,
      "employee": [
        { "id": 1, "name": "John"},
        { "id": 2, "name": "Michael"},
        { "id": 3, "name": "George"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "company": 2,
      "employee": [
        { "id": 1, "name": "Madonna"},
        { "id": 2, "name": "Harry"}
      ]
    }
  ]
};

  $scope.onClick=function(){      
    var count=0;
    var jsonObj = ($scope.myarr);
    angular.forEach(jsonObj.holding, function(key) {
     console.log(key);
     if(key.hasOwnProperty('employee')){
        count++; 
     }
   });
  alert('count of employee '+count);
    $scope.cnt=count;
  }
})
```

### **EDIT**

Now access `{{$scope.cnt}}` from view.

Comment: thank you, but to manage it in controller is not my problem. It should be executable in the view like `{{ tell_me_the_size_of_all_employees }}`, without clicks and if possible without calling a function in controller.

Comment: this is an example to achieve..you take the idea and apply what you like.I have edited how you access in view

Comment: Is it not possible to manage it without modifying the controller?